# Getting xml document from url with ECDSA certificate

Tags: c#, xml, ecdsa

I need the XML from an Url that has an ECDSA certifcate.
When I try to get this, I get the error:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

I tried:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (snder, cert, chain, error) => true;
```

and

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

and

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it by adding this row:

//Set the security protocol to SL12 otherwise it returns an error
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;